# How do I display display species and environmental variables only in the display of a CCA?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to display only environmental variables and labeled species points (as names only, without the point itself displayed) in a CCA ordination. The following code produces the following output.

```
library(vegan)
data("dune")
data("dune.env")

ord <- cca(dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Management + Use + Manure, data = dune.env)

ordiplot(ord)
```

[image]

How do I modify `ordiplot()` to display and labeled species points and environmental factors and to not display site points?

Comment: You want to display species name with points? or just names?

Comment: Just names. I edited the post to reflect that, and added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot(ord, type = "text", display = c("species","cn"))`

[image]